# How to send Metrics/Logs on my Prometheus to Grafana?

Tags: prometheus, grafana

In Grafana tutorial, it says `Click ‘Send Metrics/Logs’ on your Prometheus, Graphite, and Loki resources to start routing data to our metrics and logging service.`

[image]

Where do I go to get to this screen? I have already installed Prometheus and Grafana locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found already. It is at `Grafana Cloud Portal`

[image]